# Creating an hourglass for long calculations

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I was wondering is there a way I can create an hourglass that pops up when my calculations are running on my access form? My calculations, which are in a textbox, are taking a little while to complete and I just do not want my user to think the program is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DoCmd.Hourglass True
'...
DoCmd.Hourglass False
```

Comment: Where would I put this if the equation is in the textbox?

Comment: This is VBA code. I assumed you used VBA for calcuation because you tagged access-vba. Do you mean the calculation is an expression?
I am not sure if this is possible then because I do not know any event that fires before and after an integrated expression. Sorry. Maybe you should consider using VBA for calculations.

Comment: Oh ok I didnt even think about doing the equation in vba would I just code it in the afterupdate part of the textbox that calculates the total?

Comment: If you do the calculation in vba, you should recalculate it after updating every field, that is involved in the calculation. I would recommend to create your own sub for the calculation and call it after the update of a relevant field.